# MapSurfer.Net C# - Adding a marker to the rendered map by using given coordinates

Tags: c#, dictionary, coordinates

I just started a new project where I need to see very many  coordinates (at least 300.000) as markers (points) on a map. I decided to use MapSurfer because there I can render the map which has a better performance than like with Gmap.

My Question is how to implement markers with given coordinates on MapSurfer map.
Is there a possibility to use a overlay and add it to the map? or how can I deal with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you found any solution regarding this problem?

Comment: @IdevDev, yes. I have built my own map. I am using OSM and building an image with those tiles. as an overlay I am just using different pictureboxes and always adding them to the picturebox-control which is one below. Also I set them to Color.Transparent. It works pretty fine. I am using Graphics to draw the coordinates on a bitmap which I save and then load afterwards as an image into the PBox